# The Sorgenfrey plane and the Niemytzki plane are Baire spaces

Tags: general-topology, baire-category, sorgenfrey-line, moore-plane

A space $X$ is called a [Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space) if every countable intersection of open dense sets is dense.  By the Baire category theorem, every complete metric space is Baire and every locally compact Hausdorff space is Baire.

The [Sorgenfrey line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) is an example of a Baire space (shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476821)) that is not metrizable and not locally compact.

The [Sorgenfrey plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane) and the [Niemytzki/Moore plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane) are also not metrizable and not locally compact, and are not even normal.

For reference, I'd like a proof that the Sorgenfrey plane and the Niemytzki plane are Baire spaces. Sketch of proof is fine.

Comment: For the  Sorgenfrey plane, see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476821/mathbbr-s-sorgenfrey-line-is-a-baire-space).

Comment: @J.-E.Pin actually that link is for the Sorgenfrey line, not Sorgenfrey plane.

Comment: You are right, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the Moore plane: If a space has an dense subspace which is a Baire space, then the space itself is Baire. The open half-plane is dense in the Moore plane and is Baire.

Answer (score 4):

Both your spaces are examples of pseudocomplete spaces (see [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2709443/4280) for more links etc.) and are Baire for that reason.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ and $T$ be topologies on a set $X$ with $S\subset T$. For $t\in T$ let $t^*=Int_S(t).$ Suppose $Cl_T(t^*)=Cl_T(t)$ for every $t\in T.$ (Equivalently, that $t^*$ is $T$-dense in $t$ for every $t\in T.$) Prove that if $(X,S)$ is Baire then $(X,T)$ is Baire by showing that (1) if $Y\subset X$ is $S$-dense then $Y$ is $T$-dense, and (2) if $\{t_n:n\in \Bbb N\} \subset T$ with each $t_n$ being $T$-dense then consider $Y=\cap \{t_n^*:n\in \Bbb N\}.$

For your Q let $S$ be the "usual" metric topology.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct proof for the Sorgenfrey plane $X$.  The topology for $X$ admits as a basis the collection of all half-open rectangles $[a,b)\times[c,d)$ with $a<b$ and $c<d$.  A simple but useful fact is that any such half-open rectangle contains a closed rectangle $[a',b']\times[c',d']$ with nonempty interior in $X$.

To show that $X$ is Baire, assume we have a sequence of dense open sets $(U_n)_n$.  Given an arbitrary nonempty set $O\subseteq X$, we have to show that $O\cap\bigcap_n U_n\ne\varnothing$.  The intersection $O\cap U_1$ is open and nonempty by density of $U_1$.  So it contains a half-open rectangle, which itself contains a closed rectangle $R_1=[a_1,b_1]\times[c_1,d_1]$ with nonempty interior as explained above.  The interior of $R_1$ meets $U_2$ by density of $U_2$, so their intersection contains a half-open rectangle, which itself contains a closed rectangle $R_2$ with nonempty interior, etc.  Continuing in this way, we get a nested sequence of closed rectangles $R_n=[a_n,b_n]\times[c_n,d_n]\subseteq U_n$.  By compactness with respect to the usual topology of the plane the intersection $\bigcap_n R_n$ is nonempty, and is contained in $O\cap\bigcap_n U_n$.

---

The proof above is entirely self contained, not requiring the knowledge that the plane with the Euclidean topology is Baire.

If instead one wants to assume the result that the Euclidean plane is Baire, one can use the following (repeating the comments of David Hartley and the answer by Daniel Wainfleet).

Suppose we have a set $X$ and two topologies $\sigma$ and $\tau$ on it, not necessarily comparable, but satisfying the condition:

> (*) Every nonempty member of $\sigma$ contains a nonempty member of $\tau$ and vice versa.

**Lemma 1:** The dense sets in $X$ are the same for the two topologies.  In other words, given $A\subseteq X$, $\operatorname{cl}_\sigma(A)=X$ if and only if $\operatorname{cl}_\tau(A)=X$.

**Lemma 2:** If $U\subseteq X$ is open and dense in $(X,\sigma)$, then $O=\operatorname{int}_\tau(U)$ is open and dense in $(X,\tau)$.

**Proposition:** Under assumption (*) above, if $(X,\tau)$ is a Baire space, so is $(X,\sigma)$.

(The proofs are not difficult.)

Comment: I assume you mean the Sorgerfrey plane?

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated. All you need is that the half-open rectangles contain non-empty open rectangles. More generally, if we have a Baire topology and a finer topology with the property that every non-empty open set contains a non-empty set of the coarser topology, then the finer topology is also Baire. The Sorgerfrey line and plane and Moore plane all have this property (with the Euclidean topology as the coarser partner). This is essentially Daniel's answer, his property about the closures of the interiors is equivalent. So I think his answer is more deserving of the acceptance.

Comment: A little more generally: If two topologies (on the same set) have the property that every non-empty member of one contains a non-empty member of the other, then if one is Baire so is the other.

Comment: @DavidHartley Incorporated your comments.  Thanks.